# Multiply a matrix by a vector

Tags: matrix

I have one `3x2` matrix of coordinates in the following form

```
       a={{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}},
        {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
        {{0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}
```

I need to multiply it by another `2x1` matrix of the form

```
      b={{0},
         {2}}
```

so that the result is a product with coordinates of the form

```
      a*b={{x,y,z},
           {a,b,c},
           {p,q,r}}
```

A mere multiplication `a*b` or `a.b`  does not help because the dimension of the first matrix is taken as  `3x2x3`. How do I multiply these?

Comment: Your `a` matrix has three 2x3 matrices. To multiply by the 2x1 vector `b`, you'll have to use [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html?q=Transpose). It looks like you'll also have to do that to place it in desired form. This is just one way to do this in _Mathematica_.

Comment: Could we have a definition of what sort of matrix multiplication you are thinking about? Presumably you don't mean the ordinary multiplication were an n X r matrix is multiplied by a r X m matrix to produce a n X m matrix.

Comment: `Transpose[a, {1, 3, 2}].b` is one way to get an answer with the dimensions you request.

Comment: @Sameeran, you should have a look at the [Vectors and Matrices](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VectorsAndMatrices.html) tutorial in the documentation. Your assertion that `a` is `3x2` when in fact it is `3x2x3` is the crux of the problem. Once you understand what its dimensions are then all else will fall into place.